# how to show photos in page control?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uipagecontrol

I am trying to show photos in `UIPageControl`

I don't know how to use `UIPageControl`. Any code or tutorial will be helpful.

Comment: Please be more precise in what you are trying to achieve and tell us what you've already tried in order to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try [this](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ddpagecontrol). Its very simple and also contains image view.

Let me know if you need any other help for this.

Answer (score 0):

[Tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/)

And just FYI: pagecontrol  has to be used along with the scrollview...all u have to do is just implement the pagecontrol using the above tutor and add an imageview over the scrollview.....

Hope this helps

Comment: I have the same code but not getting how to add imageview for new image each time

Comment: have a single imageview object and add the same using for-loop..for all pages